# Bash: Saving exit code of command in `-e` script

Tags: bash

I've got a Bash script that's run with the `-e` flag. At some point, I want to run a Bash command, and continue whether it succeeded or not. I also want to have a variable that saves whether it succeeded or not, because later I want to do an `if` clause that's executed only if that command failed.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: What have you tried thus fa r? We can't just give you the answer. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Instead of checking the status code parameter (`$?`) you can simply check the command itself `if cmd; then ...` When using `set -e` one needs to be aware of a few things; http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that `set -e` does not quit the script if the return code is checked. Maybe you can execute your command like:

```
if <cmd>; then
    echo Success
    SUCCES=yes
else
    echo failure
    SUCCES=no
fi
```